# magmi Value Replacer not working properly

Tags: php, csv, magmi

{{ ValueRemapper::use_csv('../../var/import/xyz1.csv')->map({item.Categories}) }}

- Xyz1.csv has following value

  - Internal Use/Magmi Test Category;Fashion
  - Appliances;Electronics/Others Electronics
  - CAMERAS;Mobile Accessories/Other

Now i am trying to import three products with category as follows which i am trying to replace with the xyz1.csv

- Internal use/Magmi Test Category
- Applicances
- CAMERAS

Now When i import , Only "internal use " cateogry is mapping correctly in the backend with "Fashion" While two other raw are simply ignored by the plugin

I have used coloumn mapper plugin before to chagne the cateogry name to Categories [ Is this creating any issue ? ]
Dweeves is the one who designed this and he has helped me a lot and solved many issue so far , but he is very busy right now , i wonder if anyone has this kind exceptioal knowledge like dweeves who can help. I really like the Magmi as its superkool and super fast. Thanks to [ seb or dweeves for his efforts ]

Answer (score 0):

This is solved , all you have to

-> change column name to category id
-> now replace it with appropriate category id field

do not use values but use category id